# How to localize Watch OS 2 app name in Watch settings app on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, watchos-2, cfbundledisplayname

I am trying to localize my Watch OS 2 app name in Watch settings app on iPhone. The name can be changed in Info.plist file in watchKit app target under CFBundleDisplayName key. But when I add key CFBundleDisplayName to my localized InfoPlist.strings files, its used only for app name when the app is loading on watch. The name is not localized in Watch settings app on iPhone. Apple tells in [their documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1892/_index.html) that name for Watch settings app is taken from ios app Info.plist file from CFBundleName key, but this seems to not be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug. You could report it to Apple again to raise some awareness with referencing the exiting reports at openradar. I am also struggling with this and have not yet find any workaround to make the settings app display a decent value. Still in some areas of the settings app are ok, e.g. check the Notifications setting in the iPhone's Watch App and the Watch App name is shown correctly (see screenshots below with app "*Shopping List*" vs. "*Auf der Liste*") - this is valid for WatchOS 3 and iOS 10.

> [The iPhone's Watch app does not localize app names](http://www.openradar.me/27320170)

[image: Notifications section shows localized name]
[image: Application list section does not show localised name]

Comment: Do you have "Bundle display name" in the Watch App info.plist?

Comment: @kelin Yes, I have setup InfoPlist.strings providing localized versions for both `CFBundleDisplayName = "Auf der Liste"; CFBundleName = "Auf der Liste";` On the watch itselft the local name is used, also partly in the iPhone Watch App, but not in any case as seen above in the screenshots.